# Solve me and be like me

Tags: riddle

When i'm dead it is the end
But those who reach the end, they will become me

Some people know me for my hairstyle
Some know me for my friend lucille

You might know me because of my mighty roar
Or you know me because of my silly waddle

**Hint:**

> games, music and animals

Comment: Good one! :) 123

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surely you must be

> King.

When i'm dead it is the end

> Checkmate

But those who reach the end, they will become me

> In the game of [draughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts) (checkers), men reaching the kings row (the back rank) are crowned (promoted) into kings

Some people know me for my hairstyle

> [The King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley)'s pompadour is pretty much synonymous with rock 'n' roll. The pompadour hairstyle itself is often called just "[the Elvis cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompadour_(hairstyle)#Men's_styles)".

Some know me for my friend lucille

> Lucille is the name of [B.B.King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.B._King)'s guitar

You might know me because of my mighty roar

> [The Lion King](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110357/)

Or you know me because of my silly waddle

> [King Penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_penguin)

Comment: Well done, there is also a feel good hint in the title ;)

Comment: Wild guess, but could the title be a reference to "Be a King" by E-Dubble?

Comment: Don't know it. So, no :P